# Call Matlab from Intel Fortran (Linux)

Tags: linux, matlab, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am trying to integrate a Matlab program I wrote into some Fortran code. I tried to follow the example Mathworks [provides](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-fortran-applications.html). But I can't get it to compile because I can't find the header files it requests.

Does anyone know of an example of someone getting it to work on Linux using an Intel compiler. I think that might be part of the problem because Matlab only supports GNU Fortran on Linux.

And I realize this is a simple question, I just don't understand how to do anything in compiling more complicated than including multiple files with defined paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm currently using OS X so I can only provide output from OS X but everything should transfer easily over to Linux due to the Unix base. I also don't have the Intel Fortran compiler on OS X (only the C/C++ compiler).

---

**Note:** You will need to substitute the paths I use for the correct paths on your system depending on your MATLAB installation directory.

---

This issue isn't specific to the Intel Compiler, I also receive errors with the GCC Fortran compiler.

```
$ gfortran fengdemo.F 
fengdemo.F:1:0:

 #include "fintrf.h"
 ^
Fatal Error: fintrf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

You can use the Unix `locate` command to find files.

```
$ locate fintrf.h
/Applications/Matlab R2014a.app/extern/include/fintrf.h
```

In the directory where `fengdemo.F` is we can then pass the correct directory in using the `-I` option

```
-I../../include/
```

However, this produces linking errors as we haven't specified where the libraries for `fintrf.h` can be found. We can do this with the `-L` option (you will need to replace `maci64` with the correct option for Linux - I can't remember it off the top of my head but you should be able to see it in the `bin` directory)

```
-L../../../bin/maci64/
```

Now we need to tell it what libraries to use with `-leng -lmx` and so the completed command is

```
$ ifort fengdemo.F -I../../include/ -L../../../bin/maci64/ -leng -lmx
```

and it should compile correctly.

We aren't finished yet though as it won't execute. We need to set up our `PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables correctly. Specifically we need to add the `bin` and `bin/maci64` directories of our MATLAB installation to `PATH`

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Matlab\ R2014a.app/bin/maci64:/Applications/Matlab\ R2014a.app/bin
```

and the `bin/maci64/` and `sys/os/maci64/` to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/Matlab\ R2014a.app/bin/maci64/:/Applications/Matlab\ R2014a.app/sys/os/maci64/
```

**Note:** On Linux `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Thanks to [Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721644/vladimir-f) for correcting me.

Now you can execute the program using

```
$ ./a.out
```

Comment: Note: Linux uses LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Thank you for your help. A few things:
1) I don't have the maci64 folder. Would my equivalent be glnxa64?
2) When I try to compile with the `-leng -lmx`, I get the error `ld: cannot find -leng` or `-lmx`
3) When I try and add `PATH=$PATH:/afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/matlab/8.5`, I get the error `Bad : modifier in $ (/).`.
Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: @user1543042 Yes its `glnxa64`. I just couldn't remember what exactly it was. If your environment variables aren't set you won't be able to find `-leng` and `-lmx`. The error may have to do with your shell, which shell are you using?

Comment: @IKavanagh: I'm trying to get it to work on csh, but I'm also trying it locally on bash.
So the commands I'm trying to run on csh are:
`set PATH=${PATH}:${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/:${matlabroot}/bin`
`set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/:${matlabroot}/sys/os/glnxa64/`
`ifort ${matlabroot}/extern/examples/eng_mat/fengdemo.F -I${matlabroot}/extern/include/ -L${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/ -leng -lmx -o a`
    And I get pages says this not found and that not found.

Comment: When I run it locally I can get it to compile using gfortran but when I try and run it I get the error `Can't start MATLAB engine`

Comment: @user1543042 The `csh` shell is different so there may be some slight differences to what I've posted above. For instance I think you need `setenv` versus `export`. Do you have a `matlabroot` variable set? That could be why.

Comment: I believe that there are files missing from the install so I asked the engineers who manage the cluster to take a look. I was more concerned that the bash compiled won't run.

Comment: @user1543042 Ok, best of luck with it.

Comment: Am I missing something in the path additions? Because on my local machine it will compile but when I try to run, the MATLAB engine won't start.

Comment: @user1543042 Have you fixed the issue? I won't be near Linux until tomorrow so can't help with debugging until then.

Comment: Sort of. For whatever reason the version of Matlab I was using doesn't work but 2014b does for gfortran. Now I just needed to understand why it works for gfortran but not ifort.