# Call Matlab from Intel Fortran on Linux

Tags: linux, matlab, fortran, intel-fortran

Editted:

This is building on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769469/call-matlab-from-intel-fortran-linux/32769925#32769925).

With the answer, I am able to compile and run with gfortran however, I am still unable to run with ifort. The commands I am using to compile in tcsh are:

```
set PATH=${PATH}:${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/:${matlabroot}/bin
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/:${matlabroot}/sys/os/glnxa64/
${FC} ${matlabroot}/extern/examples/eng_mat/fengdemo.F -I${matlabroot}/extern/include/ -L${matlabroot}/bin/glnxa64/ -leng -lmx -cpp -o FEngDemo
```

Do I need to make changes to the libraries I use? To the Fortran code? Or to the Matlab code?

Any help would be appreciated.

The Fortran code is:

```
#include "fintrf.h"
C
#if 0
C
C     fengdemo.F
C     .F file need to be preprocessed to generate .for equivalent
C
#endif
C
C     fengdemo.f
C
C     This is a simple program that illustrates how to call the MATLAB
C     Engine functions from a FORTRAN program.
C
C Copyright 1984-2011 The MathWorks, Inc.
C======================================================================
C 

      program main

C     Declarations
      implicit none

      mwPointer engOpen, engGetVariable, mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer ep, T, D 
      double precision time(10), dist(10)
      integer engPutVariable, engEvalString, engClose
      integer temp, status
      mwSize i
      data time / 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 /

      mwSize M, N
      parameter(M=1) 
      parameter(N=10) 

C
      ep = engOpen('matlab ')
C
      if (ep .eq. 0) then
         write(6,*) 'Can''t start MATLAB engine'
         stop
      endif
C
      T = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, N, 0)
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(time, mxGetPr(T), N)
C
C
C     Place the variable T into the MATLAB workspace
C
      status = engPutVariable(ep, 'T', T)
C
      if (status .ne. 0) then 
         write(6,*) 'engPutVariable failed'
         stop
      endif
C
C
C     Evaluate a function of time, distance = (1/2)g.*t.^2
C     (g is the acceleration due to gravity)
C     
      if (engEvalString(ep, 'D = .5.*(-9.8).*T.^2;') .ne. 0) then
         write(6,*) 'engEvalString failed'
         stop
      endif
C
C
C     Plot the result
C
      if (engEvalString(ep, 'plot(T,D);') .ne. 0) then 
       write(6,*) 'engEvalString failed'
         stop
      endif

      if (engEvalString(ep, 'title(''Position vs. Time'')') .ne. 0) then
          write(6,*) 'engEvalString failed'
          stop
      endif

      if (engEvalString(ep, 'xlabel(''Time (seconds)'')') .ne. 0) then
          write(6,*) 'engEvalString failed'
          stop
      endif
      if (engEvalString(ep, 'ylabel(''Position (meters)'')') .ne. 0)then
          write(6,*) 'engEvalString failed'
          stop
      endif
C     
C     
C     read from console to make sure that we pause long enough to be
C     able to see the plot
C     
      print *, 'Type 0 <return> to Exit'
      print *, 'Type 1 <return> to continue'

      read(*,*) temp
C
      if (temp.eq.0) then
         print *, 'EXIT!'
         status = engClose(ep)

         if (status .ne. 0) then 
            write(6,*) 'engClose failed'
         endif

         stop
      end if
C
      if (engEvalString(ep, 'close;') .ne. 0) then
         write(6,*) 'engEvalString failed'
         stop
      endif 
C      
      D = engGetVariable(ep, 'D')
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(mxGetPr(D), dist, N)
      print *, 'MATLAB computed the following distances:'
      print *, '  time(s)  distance(m)'
      do 10 i=1,10
         print 20, time(i), dist(i)
 20      format(' ', G10.3, G10.3)
 10   continue
C   
C     
      call mxDestroyArray(T)
      call mxDestroyArray(D)
      status = engClose(ep)
C      
      if (status .ne. 0) then 
         write(6,*) 'engClose failed'
         stop
      endif
C
      stop
      end
```

With the `-g` and `-traceback` flags, the error I get at runtime is:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source                                                                 
FEngDemo           0000000000477619  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FEngDemo           0000000000475EEE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FEngDemo           000000000044D8F2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FEngDemo           0000000000431573  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FEngDemo           00000000004041FB  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread.so.0    0000003E1D80F790  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libmx.so           00007F5F077FCED7  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FEngDemo           00000000004032ED  MAIN__                     46  fengdemo.F
FEngDemo           0000000000403186  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          0000003E1D01ED5D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FEngDemo           0000000000403009  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Comment: It segFaults on line 46, `call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(time, mxGetPr(T), N)`.

Comment: If it segfaults, then it **does** compile. Mex is a tricky thing and it usuallly takes a while to properly dimensionalize everything and to use proper types for input parameters for the `mx*` functions. For this you'll need the actual fortran code...

Comment: You're getting there. Now post your compile errors or runtime errors, depending on what you get. With you reputation you should be aware that "this doesn't work" by itself is not a proper question.

Comment: Which line is 46? Did you also try the `-check` option?

Comment: Line 46 is `call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(time, mxGetPr(T), N)`. I had never heard of the `-check` flag but it didn't change the output.

Comment: This doesn't explain your error, but you should make sure that every `gfortran` switch has been changed to the appropriate `ifort` one. For instance, while `-cpp` is supported for backwards compatibility reasons, the standard switch in `ifort` is `-fpp`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you. I wasn't sure what the difference between the `cpp` and `fpp` flags was.